Adapter from garden hose to shower head
I'm trying to build a outdoor solar shower to rinse off from garden work. I'm looking to feed  low-cost shower head from a 4gal plastic water tank. I'm assuming I'm going to want to attach a garden hose the plastic tank to gravity feed a mounted shower head.
So I'm looking for some type adapter to switch from garden hose to a shower head spec. I've seen the other way around. I may need to make a custom hose, one with a garden hose tip on one side and shower head tip on the other. I've got no problem with that I just needed to know the specs of the tips.

Search for garden hose shower heads.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=garden+hose+npt+afapter&iax=images&ia=images

I believe in the US shower heads have 1/2" NPT. That doesn't match to a garden hose but you could  add an adapter to a garden hose.
Or clamp the garden hose to a drop elbow and add the shower arm and head.

Adapters between pipe thread and hose thread are available at most serious hardware stores. Or online or wherever.
